# Create a box and whisker plot in Excel 2016

Tags: microsoft-excel, powerpivot

I asked this question on StackOverflow as well, but I realized that this site may be more likely to produce an answer.  My question is: how to create a Box and Whisker plot in Excel 2016?

I know that a box plot chart type is not available in Excel 2013 and below. To my pleasure, however, recently I read that Microsoft added this (and some other) chart types to Excel 2016.  Hence, I installed the Excel 2016 preview. Unfortunately, however, I haven't been able to find the chart type.

I have my data imported into PowerPivot from SQL Server, so I'd prefer to use PowerPivot for this. Does anyone know how? Maybe I didn't do it right...

See for example the following presentation from Microsoft Ignite conference:
https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Ignite/2015/BRK3564
(Minute 20-22)

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could find is here:

[Excel Unplugged - New Charts in Excel 2016](http://excelunplugged.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/052515_2013_NewChartsin4.png)

It seems that "Box & Whisker" charts can be found when you create a chart (Insert tab --> Insert Graph option) and select "All charts".  [This image](http://excelunplugged.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/052515_2013_NewChartsin4.png) shows that dialog and the "Box & Whisker" option.

Comment: Ah thanks! That's an article I didnt see yet. In the comments to the article, it says the new chart types aren't added to the public preview yet.  So, I guess I have to ask Microsoft about it.